# Convert DD MM YY to Datetime Object in a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In a current pandas series, I have numerous rows in which the date is formatted in the format YY MM DD, with the months being the text abbreviation of the month. For example, 19 JA 02 represents January 2, 2019. Is there a way to convert and parse this series to a datetime object?

I have currently tried the following:

```
chemical_19['Manufacture Date(MM/DD/YYYY)'].apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%M/%d'))
```

Comment: you could be looking for `pd.to_datetime`, but the problem is the two-letter month abbreviation is not a standard way for the method, check this table out https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior for the standard ways, and use `.str.replace` to replace them, before using `pd.to_datetime(..., format=".........")`

Comment: for `Jan` you could use `%b` but for `JA` it may need to create own function which use dictionary `{"JA": 1, "FE": 2, ...}`  or `{"JA": "Jan", "FE": "Feb", ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have `Jan`, `Feb` then you could use `%b` to match month.
And `'%y %b %d'` to match `19 Jan 02`

But in `pandas` you can use dictionary `{'JA': 'Jan', 'FE':'Feb', ...}`
with `.replace(..., regex=True)` to change names

And later use `pd.to_datetime()` with `'%y %b %d'`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'date': ["19 JA 02", "06 FE 14"],
})    
print(df)

df['date'] = df['date'].replace({'JA': 'Jan', 'FE':'Feb'}, regex=True)
print(df)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y %b %d')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
       date
0  19 JA 02
1  06 FE 14

        date
0  19 Jan 02
1  06 Feb 14

        date
0 2019-01-02
1 2006-02-14
```